# White bar at the bottom of my website

Tags: html, css, whitespace

On the bottom of my website, BJBGaming1.com, there is a weird white bar, please help me get rid of it. and my coding is

```html
   <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>BJBGaming1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="top-bar">
<div class="top-bar-left">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Minecraft.html">Minecraft</a></li>
<li><a href="CS_GO.html">CS:GO</a></li>
<li><a href="Smite.html">Smite</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="callout large primary">
<div class="row column text-center">
<h1 style="color:green">BJBGaming1</h1>
<h2 class="subheader">Happy Thanksgiving!</h2>
</div>
</div>

<div style="color:black" class="row medium-8 large-7 columns">
<div class="blog-post">
<h3>Minecraft <small>11/25/2015</small></h3>
<img class="thumbnail" src="Minecraft.png">
<p style="color:white">Minecraft is a very popular game, on PC, Xbox, and     Smart Phones, played by millions of people every day. For more information go to     www.bjbgaming1.com/minecraft</p>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div style="color:black" class="row medium-8 large-7 columns">
<div class="blog-post">
<h3>CS:GO <small>11/25/2015</small></h3>
<img class="thumbnail" src="CS.GO.png">
<p style="color:white">CS:GO stand for, Counter-Strike: Global Offensive,  and is a FPS game that is assosiated with E-Sports, and played by millions of people everyday. For more information go to www.bjbgaming1.com/cs_go</p>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div style="color:black" class="row medium-8 large-7 columns">
<div class="blog-post">
<h3>Smite <small>11/25/2015</small></h3>
<img class="thumbnail" src="Smite.png">
<p style="color:white">Smite is a game just like LoL (League of Legends). In     Smite you can pick from over 50 gods that ou unlock with Favor, favor is     basically the currency to buy gods, but in Smite there are tons of different game modes, and every day they feature a community made gamemode. Also, Smite is always coming out with new gamemodes to try. For more information go to www.bjbgaming1.com/smite</p>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- begin wwww.htmlcommentbox.com -->
<div style="color:white" id="HCB_comment_box"><a  href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com">Comment Form</a> is loading comments...     </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="//www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/skins/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap.css?v=0" />
<script type="text/javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user)  {hcb_user={};} (function(){var s=document.createElement("script"),    l=hcb_user.PAGE || (""+window.location).replace(/'/g,"%27"),  h="//www.htmlcommentbox.com";s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttri bute("src", h+"/jread?page="+encodeURIComponent(l).replace("+","%2B")+"&mod=%241%24wq1rdBcg%24nHgonDoa 62nAhjUsN9BAt%2F"+"&opts=16862&num=10&ts=1448559904895");if (typeof   s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})();   /*-->*/ </script>
<!-- end www.htmlcommentbox.com -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.js">          </script>
<script>
 $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Im probably missing some code so its probably best that you look at it from bjbgaming1.com

Comment: please try to make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link for these long codes

Comment: Your css seems to be minified and can't be read easily, can you please upload unminified version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add background color to the "body" tag of this website by using CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

The bottom of your background image is black so add black background to 'extend' the background image.